# AppStoreでのユーザーレビューは１アプリに対して複数回可能か？

Tags: ios, app-store

レビューを促す機構をアプリに組み込むことを検討しています。
iosアプリに対しては、ユーザー（１つのApple ID）が複数回同じアプリに対してレビューすることは可能でしょうか？

１アプリに対し、１ユーザーが

・１投稿のみ
or
・バージョンに対して１投稿
or
・何度でも（たぶん出来ないと思うけど）

どれでしょう？

また複数回出来る場合に、レビューコメントは更新されて最新のもののみ参照出来るようになるということでしょうか？

どなたかご存知でしたらお願いします。

Comment: 既に公開されている他のアプリ(他の方のアプリ)に、実際にレビューを何度もつけてみては？

Comment: ありがとうございます。実際に試してみましたが、カウントされているのかどうか分からなかったので質問させて頂きました。もしご存知の方がいればと思いまして。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おおむね自分で試したところの知見を共有しておきます。

**結論：評価件数は変わらないが、星もコメントも更新されるようです。**

例えば、アプリのver 1.00で
「星４、コメント：あああ」

と書いたユーザーが

ver 1.01で
「星５、コメント：いいい」

とした場合に、
「星５、コメント：いいい」のみ有効になるようです。
評価件数は更新なので増えないということになりますが、
現在のバージョンにおける評価には表示されるようです。